# Set content in JNLP dynamically

Tags: dynamic, jnlp

I'm deploying a Cisco Appliance that uses JNLP to install the client side applications.  I modified a few of their `.sh` scripts to grab some information dynamically and I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same thing in some `JNLP` files.

`i.e.`

`<jnlp spec="1.0"
      codebase="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/dcnm-client"
      href="dcnm.jnlp">`

Can I set the IP based on the result of the command line...or could I set an `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` and use that?